# NEAR protocol: How to ensure that function call came from multisig contract

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I have 2 contracts:

- first one is multisig2 from https://github.com/near/core-contracts/tree/master/multisig2 deployed on testnet at `multisig.company1.mtestaccount.testnet`
- second one is my custom contract with a 'privileged' method `issue_new_shares` that should only be called from the multisig2 contract after 2 confirmations (let's say `alice.testnet` followed by `bob.testnet`).

In my custom contract, I am checking that the predecessor is the multisig2 contract. Is this sufficient to enforce the 'privilege'? Any security issue with this approach?

```
#[near_bindgen]
impl Contract {
  pub fn issue_new_shares(&mut self, num_new_shares: u32) {
    self.verify_caller();
    // do privileged stuff
  }

  // allowed_admin_caller is initialized to multisig.company1.mtestaccount.testnet
  fn verify_caller(&self) {
    assert!(self.allowed_admin_caller == env::predecessor_account_id(), 
      "Privileged method can only be invoked by authorized multisig contract as the predecessor");
  }
}
```

Docs mention that we should check the signer_account_id() for security. However in this case, the 4 authorized entities who can confirm (including alice and bob) are defined in multisig2. My custom contract has no knowledge of them, so I cannot check the signer_account_id. Is my approach to check `predecessor_account_id` sane, or am I missing a big security gap here?

Answer (score 1):

Hopped on a call during NEAR office hours and the dev team confirmed that checking `predecessor_account_id` is the right approach in this case. I am set for now!

Also, this is a great reference to read through: https://medium.com/near-devs/5-things-i-wish-someone-had-told-me-while-learning-to-make-smart-contracts-1b02441ee162